# Trouble using jquery-csv library

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jquery-csv

As I am using React in ES6 and am using [Jquery-CSV library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-csv),
I was unable to import using

```
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery');
require('./jquery.csv.js');
```

Found a way to import using

```
import * as randomName from 'jquery-csv'
```

Now how am I able to use

````
$.csv.toArrays(csv);```/```$.csv.toObjects(csv);?
````

I tried to play around by using names as prefix like `randomName.csv.toArrays()` but no luck.

### EDIT:

---

`randomName.toArray(csv);` this works,

but now I am getting the following error

`TypeError: csv.replace is not a function`

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Able to access the library and while passing string as input, I am able to get the them in Array.

`input="This is a Random string"`

> `randomName.csv.toArray(input)`

Output: `["This is a Random string"]`

Answer (score 0):

Same result here using React

```
import $ from 'jquery'
var csv  = $.csv = require('jquery-csv');
var input="This is a Random string"
tableau_d = csv.toArray(input)
alert(tableau_d)
```

Output : `"This is a Random string"`